# How to remove a selected rows from dataframe under a condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large data with 12 columns. Where MatchId is duplicated.

```
df1.columns
Out[569]: 
Index(['MatchId', 'Event_Id', 'EventCode', 'Team1', 'Team2', 'Team1_Goals',
       'Team2_Goals', 'xG_Team1', 'xG_Team2', 'CurrentPlaytime',
       'Home_Goal_Time', 'Away_Goal_Time'],
      dtype='object')
```

For the condition, `df1.loc[df1.Home_Goal_Time >= 200, 'MatchId']`, I want all the MatchId associated with this condition to be removed from `df1`.

Comment: you can't remove cells. you can overwrite them with some new values...

Comment: I want to remove rows as long as they satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df_filtered = df1.query('Home_Goal_Time<200')
```

This would filter out the rows you are not interested in.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: It only removed the MatchId on the same row. I want all duplicated MatchId to be removed.

Comment: Try this! `df[~df['MatchId'].isin(df.query('Home_Goal_Time>=20')['MatchId'])]`.

I thought you just wanted to filter the rows where `Home_Goal_Time >= 200`. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want this:

```
df1 = df1[~df1['MatchId'].isin(df1.loc[df1.Home_Goal_Time >= 200, 'MatchId'])]
```